# CSS - Make image fit screen so no scroll bars appear

Tags: css, image

If you click to view a very big image that is higher than your screen res on google images, like this for example http://p1.pichost.me/i/32/1548022.png then it appears a `+` and `-` on cursor. The `+` makes the image have its original size, while the `-` makes the image fit the screen, `but not the full screen`, so that no scroll bars appear. I try to implement this last part on my css code but I didn't had much success, I tried setting `overflow-x:hidden;` and `overflow-y:hidden;` but this gives the original unscrollable size. What should I do? Ty

Comment: setting overflow to `hidden` will just hide part of the image, but you want to scale it to fit the screen, don't you?

Comment: Yeah but by searching fit screen on the web gives ALL results fit the exact full screen

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is easier if you use CSS background instead of the `<img>` element. We will use the `background-size: contain` property to achieve the sizing that you are looking for. With the exception of IE8, [all recent modern browsers support this property-value combination](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts).

p/s: You can change the dimensions of the image container as you please, but I'm using viewport units to best illustrate the example.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  }
div.img {
  background-image: url('http://p1.pichost.me/i/32/1548022.png');
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  }
```

```html
<div class="img"></div>
```

Comment: It wasn't really mentioned here, but the thing that actually makes the scrollbars go away is the fact that you've set `margin: 0; padding: 0;` for the body, not any of the image/bg specs.. Thought I'd mention that for those bumping into this, like me, through a search..

Answer (score 1):

First you need to set width and height of body or the outer div or element of the image

```
body or #div{
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
}
```

Then set your img width and height to 100% or background-size to 100% 100%

Answer (score 0):

If you bind the image on `<img>`, then make that image element flexible by setting

```
/* your css and you img */
#your-image { 
    width:100%;
    height:100%; 
}
```

If you bind the image on some element as its background...

```
/* your css and your element */
#some-element { 
    background-image:url(/*path*/);
    background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

It looks like you want to show the whole large image only in a page. So your `<body>` element or a nested wrapper element will be a good candidate for the `css`

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays we have `object-fit` readily available.

However, I discovered that in some cases, like when the container element boundaries are met, you need to add **`display:block`** to the image, otherwise scrollbars would appear, no matter what (for example `display:inline-block` doesn't work). This is the simplest method I've found to show the full image and nothing else:

```
<style>
body {margin:0px;}
img {
    height:100vh;
    width:100vw;
    object-fit:contain;
    display:block;
}
</style>

<body><img src="big-image.jpg"></body>
```

Also, if you want to use % unit for the image, you have to set width and height (in something more concrete than %) for the container. Even when using `object-fit:cover`, you need to set `display:block` for the image.

```
<style>
body {
    height:100vh;
    width:100vw;
    margin:0px;
}
img {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    object-fit:cover;
    display:block;
}
</style>

<body><img src="big-image.jpg"></body>
```

Or you could have it without `display:block` and with `height:100%` and no other heights, if you leave out `<!DOCTYPE html>`, and you can omit other things too, but I don't recommend these things. Also, in many situations you might not see the benefit of `display:block` for the image, but it can be a good practice to prevent future problems brought by outlier cases. You can still have the container element with some other display value.

Additionally, we also now have new dynamic viewport units, `dvh` for height (not so readily available, but it can be handy), if you want to avoid content overflowing on mobile browsers, where the browser might add UI elements that decrease the available space.